# ¿Cómo alinear divs verticalmente al lado derecho y un div al lado izquierdo?

Tags: html, css3

¿Cómo pongo un div al lado izquierdo?, como el de la imagen de abajo.

```css
   #container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  border:1px solid;
  background-color: #e4e3e4;
}

#resultado1,#resultado2,#resultado3,#resultado4 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
margin-left:auto; margin-right:0;

}
#izq{
text-align:center;
border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
   <div id="container">
  <div id="izq">80</div>
  <div id="resultado1">60</div>
  <div id="resultado2">50</div>
  <div id="resultado3">34</div>
  <div id="resultado4">23</div>
</div>
```

quiero que quede así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar mejor lo que tratas de hacer o en su defecto poner una imagen de cómo debería verse?

Comment: @Guz puse una imagen de lo que quiero

Comment: @Guz esta bien gracias,100%;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en tu maquetado. Una maquetación correcta hace posible cualquier layout que tengas en mente. En tu caso, yo pondría dos secciones: una para el contenido (área grande) y otra para el aside vertical. El área grande debe tener, de preferencia, `flex: 1` para que siempre ocupe el tamaño que deja disponible el aside.

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid #777;
  display: flex;
  padding: 12px;
}

.container .content {
  border: 2px solid #777;
  flex: 1;
}

.container .side {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.container .side div  {
  border: 2px solid #777;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.container .side div:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <article class="content">
    
  </article>
  <aside class="side">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  border:1px solid;
  background-color: #e4e3e4;
}

#resultado1,#resultado2,#resultado3,#resultado4 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
margin-left:auto; margin-right:0;

}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="resultado1"></div>
  <div id="resultado2"></div>
  <div id="resultado3"></div>
  <div id="resultado4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: no funciona, el contenedor `container` se achica y recorre al lado derecho

Comment: He editado, alineando a la derecha solo los #resultado1, etc.

Comment: una consulta mas, como puedo crear otro div que se situe en el centro? edite mi pregunta.